# What is wrong with my cat's eye

Tags: cats, infections, eye-disease

She is my recent rescue. I rescue barn kittens from farmers who don’t want them around or if they have dogs who in’s them better as chew toys. But she came to us with some gunky infected eyes and have been cleaning them out multiple times a day with warm water, as I normally do with all of the kittens who come through. But she has one good eye and the other may look like she is blind, but she shows no signs of blindness (running into things, trouble finding food and litter). She also has some pretty good reflexes. I’m not sure if I was doing it right, though; I never dealt with this before. Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you are in worry about the health of your pet, please see a vet! Do not wait for the guesses of strangers from the internet! For the well-being of the pets, this kind of question were classified as "out of range of pets.SE" and will be closed.

Answer (score 6):

The eye of your cat is cloudy, that much is clear. But there are different types of cloudy eyes.

A [cataract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cataract) is "only" a cloudy lens and can be treated by an operation.

A [cloudy cornea](https://www.mountsinai.org/health-library/symptoms/cloudy-cornea) affects the (usually transparent) skin of the eyeball and covers the pupil and iris. This is what your cat has and there is no appropriate home care. You should get her treated by a vet.

---

The reason why her one eye became milky is probably the infection. The bacteria may have moved inside the eyeball or at least infected the cornea, the outer skin of the eyeball. If that is the case, the infection **must be treated by a veterinarian** or it might flare up again and again. In the worst case, the eye must be removed to stop the infection. Better start the treatment before it gets to that.

Right now, there is no doubt that her milky eye is blind and once the transparent skin becomes milky, it cannot be reverted.

However, her behavior is a clear indication that her other eye works fine and she can have a very happy and healthy life, once the infection in the milky eye is properly treated.

---

The cloudy eye is still red and she seems to squint it more than the clear eye, which indicates that it's still badly infected and causes her pain. The vet will probably prescribe antibiotic eye drops or oral antibiotics for her. As with any antibiotics, you must complete the entire course, even if the cat doesn't show any symptoms anymore.

Whenever you clean her eyes, first clean the clear eye, then the milky one. Do not transfer bacteria from the milky eye into the clear one.

Comment: Worth adding that cats with healthy eyes, in fact most animals, will not normally squint just one eye without an obvious reason like rubbing their head against something. This is almost always an indication that something is in need of attention by the vet, like early stages of an infection, even if you can't see anything wrong yet. One shouldn't wait and see how it develops either, for one it is always best to get on top of things early to avoid lengthy treatments, and also since there might be rare cases where there are only a couple of hours to safely avoid blindness of the affected eye.